# Redirect to https://www but first redirect to http://www.[HOST[ instead of https://[HOST]

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Challenge: redirect a user to https:// without paying for two SSL certificates, but only for one.

Imagine you have only one SSL certificate, for www.domain.com and you want your users to access https://www.domain.com only.

The users will usually type http://domain.com

First step for you will be to redirect them straight to https://www.

I could do that via code, but I'd like to do it via .htaccess since the code is running in a dev/test environment with different hostnames and I'd like apache to handle the redirect rather than coding a solution.

I've found this example online:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The problem with this is that it first redirects you to:

https://[HOST], then to https://www.[HOST]

But, the user will get a warning about a problem with the certificate at https://[HOST] which is fair enough, since I haven't bought one for the non-www domain.

Any idea how it would be the best to write the .htaccess rule to cater for this scenario where you first redirect to...

http://www.[HOST], then to https://www.[HOST]

...rather than to...

https://[HOST], then to https://www.[HOST]

Many thanks,
Vlad

Comment: Put the second rule first...?

Comment: did the job, many thanks!